# How to get formulas from a row and spread them in a range using script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I get this one to populate the range defined in the code?

I understand that once I get it, I have to iterate over the range to set the formulas, but I just can't get how to do it:

```
  let formulas = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8).getFormulasR1C1();
  let rngFormulas = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 8, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow(), 8)
  rngFormulas.forEach(c => rngFormulas(c).setFormulas(formulas))
```

Of course, it gives me an error as there's a lot to learn on `forEach` and a lot more.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I  misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to modify my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got rather lost in your coordinates. Please put the ones you need.

*notation: (row from num 1, column from num 1)*
What this does is it copies formulas from cell (7, 1) to (7, 8).
Then it puts them on each row from row 8 till the last row. First row is (8, 1) to (8, 8).

```js
  const formulas = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8).getFormulasR1C1();
  const lastRow = boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow();
  for (let i = 8; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    const rngFormulas = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 8)
    rngFormulas.setFormulasR1C1(formulas);
  }
```

Ask if you need more clarification!

Answer (score 1):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var src = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8);
var dst = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 8, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow(), 8);
src.copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
```

#### Note:

- If you want to copy the same formulas of `boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8)` with the same range, you can use the following modification.

  ```
    var src = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8);
    var dst = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 8, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow(), 8);
    dst.setFormulas(Array(dst.getNumRows()).fill(src.getFormulas()[0]));
  ```

#### Reference:

- [copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed)

### Added:

When I saw your script, from `let rngFormulas = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 8, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow(), 8)`, I had thought that you wanted to copy the formula of `A7:G7` to the `H8:O`. But if you want to copy the formula of `A7:G7` to the `A8:G`, you can use the following modification. As a sample script, I would like to add this because I thought that this method might be useful for other users.

```
var src = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(7, 1, 1, 8);
var dst = boqPipeworkSheet.getRange(8, 1, boqPipeworkSheet.getLastRow() - 7, 8);
src.copyTo(dst, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
```